# Rails update method not working in Rails 5 to update records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails app and in my rails app, i have an admin section. which i do the following to update a record

```
<%= link_to "Approve", admins_transaction_path(transaction, transaction: {status: 'approved'}), method: :put %>
```

and in my controller, it looks like this

```
class Admins::TransactionsController < AdminsController
  before_action :get_transaction_id, only: [:update]

  def index
    @transactions = Transaction.where(status: 'pending')
  end

  def update
    @transaction.update_attributes(transactions_params)
    redirect_to admins_transactions_path
  end

  private

  def get_transaction_id
    @transaction = Transaction.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def transactions_params
    params.require(:transaction).permit(:amount, :asset_id, :user_id, :status, :txnref)
  end
end
```

This is my log

```
    Started PUT "/admins/transactions/1?transaction%5Bstatus%5D=approved" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-19 21:17:51 +0800
    Processing by Admins::TransactionsController#update as HTML
      Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Al0iJGAbwEaLs8jixUOOANQYO7QZzQZWIMp2e2crykLyeGc/JlNHwg1AATqtWMzidhK87Td199b+P0MLguAzVw==", "transaction"=>{"status"=>"approved"}, "id"=>"1"}
      Admin Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      Transaction Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
       (0.3ms)  BEGIN
      Asset Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "assets".* FROM "assets" WHERE "assets"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "cash"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      Asset Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "assets".* FROM "assets" WHERE "assets"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
       (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admins/transactions
Completed 302 Found in 39ms (ActiveRecord: 6.8ms)
```

my transaction model

```
create_table "transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "amount"
    t.string "txnref"
    t.string "status"
    t.integer "asset_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
    t.string "type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["deleted_at"], name: "index_transactions_on_deleted_at"
  end
```

But it doesnt update my record.

Quite baffling and i am not sure what i am not doing right.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: what is your stack trace Error?

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the update methods? Are you able to print `params` to console to check.

Comment: Could you share your transaction.rb model file

Comment: What column u want to update

Comment: @bo-oz yup, i put a byebug on the method and it hits it
IsmailAkbudak done

Comment: @giridharan status column

Comment: @KingsleySimon you added db migration file, it is not model file

Comment: It sounds like the object is invalid, preventing `update_attributes` to save it https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes, Try with `update_attributes!` (with that bang) and you'll get an exception with the error.

Comment: @arieljuod yup i tried that as well. doesnt seem to work

Comment: @KingsleySimon, you should inspect object before and after the `update_attributes` call, install the `byebug` gem if you doesn't have it already and add a line `byebug` on your controller right after the `update_attributes` line, it will stop execution and you can inspect the value (try `@transaction.valid?` and if it's false check `@transaction.errors`)

Comment: @arieljuod all done and object is valid and has no errors. that is why this so weird

Comment: I aggree with @arieljuod maybe you have some callbacks in your model that is prevent to save changes or it can be any gem in your gemfile. I see in your logs Asset loading from db, maybe because of it

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
<%= link_to "Approve", admins_transaction_path(transaction, transaction: {status: 'approved'}), method: :put %>
```

**To**

```
<%= link_to "Approve", approve_path(transaction), method: :path%>
```

**Controller**

```
def approve
    @transaction.update(:status=>'approved')
    redirect_to admins_transactions_path
  end
```

**Routes**

```
patch '#yourcontroller/:id/approve',to:'#yourcontroller#approve' , as: :approve
```

Comment: you should explain why you are suggesting this changes and how does this fixes the op problem